# Button does not display

Tags: android, xml

I am using android studio and I am trying to add this button to a blank activity but the button does not appear when I run the app and I don't know what the issue is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pauseGame"
        android:onClick="pauseGame" />


</LinearLayout>
`
```

Comment: Try changing to android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: What is in `@string/pauseGame` ? Also, try `android:visibility="visible"`

Comment: @Remian8985  <string name="pauseGame">Game Pause</string>. Also android:visibility="visible"

Comment: post your main class where you use your layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pauseGame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:text="@string/pauseGame"
                android:onClick="pauseGame" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work neither. I can see the button on the design tab of android studio, but not when I run the app.

Comment: Make sure that you use right layout file in `setContentView` function in `onCreate` method of your activity @user1774537

Comment: @llya Blokh Thanks a million your response worked! I forgot that line in my class. I added this  setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);  and it's working now! Thanks

Comment: @user1774537 great! check an answer as correct please

Answer (score 1):

I got your issue Change the `LinearLayout`

`width` and `height` like

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```